# VBA which generates the result which appears the largest number of times (# of occurences)

Tags: database, excel, vba

For example If I have a database of contacts with 9 columns and 22 rows with data about these contacts (first name, name, company, email, city, country, uniqueID, initial of the person which has this contact, etc.)(I can send it to you as an example to train you)

Let's imagine that we are looking for people in this database. But you can have for example some duplicates with same name, same first name, same country, same uniqueID as a consequence (because it is constitued by firstname.name) but different companies, emails and city for a contact. Knowing that we want to make the research by uniqueID, if look for this guy you will find by Vlookup notably the first occurence of his information, I mean if the first company which appears for this guy in Company is "BNP" so, doing a Vlookup to know which is his company to put it in another database, i will find "BNP" wheareas after we can observe 5 times that people enter "HSBC" as a society for this guy so if we could take into account the number of times it appears we could have a more exact answer.

In this case as "HSBC" appears 5 times against 1 for "BNP", we would like that our research (not necessarily a Vlookup) gives us the answer "HSBC" because it is the company which appears the largest number of times. If it will be possible to do this for each other information (name, city, country, etc.).

And if we only have 2 possibilities with 2 different answers i would like that the macro looks for in the other cells of the row if it cannot find information like:

1. Check the mail to see if we cannot find its company (e.g. @gemalto.com) in it
2. Check if the mail don't finish by .fr to deduce that its country is France and not the one we have (e.g. @gemalto.fr)
3. If nothing enables to take a decision, send a msgbox to the user in order him to choose between both option for each information for which the macro doesn't have enough information to decide

I know how to use VBA but I do not have any idea on this subject. Tell me if you want me to send you a file example to try to find a solution.

Comment: it seems like using a real UniqueId(one that actually can't repeat) would solve your problem way faster than going around like that...

Comment: Suppose both **HSBC** and **CHASE** appear 5 times.....do you want both names ??

Comment: No I want either to try to find a way to decide which one is the good one checking emails (if there are 4 emails in hsbc.com for example et 3 in chase.com), or either by sending a msgbox to choose manually between different cases or otherwise by creating a multi-choice box giving the choice between the different alternatives met

Comment: Caio César S. Leonardi, I get your point but how am i going to know what the is the good information about my contacts ? Because it is the goal of this exercise, it comes to sort out a database of contacts

Answer (score 0):

I would first see if I get satisfactory results with the manual approach in Excel; if I am happy with the results I get manually then I would work on the code.
So with that in mind, try the MODE.Single() function at the head of each column or the Advanced Filter set for Unique might be your answer.
You need to get to know what is possible in Excel and how; that will go a long way to working the code, especially since you can record a lot of the code and then edit it as required.

Comment: But there is a little problem Sir, the database on which I want to apply this is constituted of almost 50 000 rows so the manual approach risks being a bit time-consuming..Hence my question

Comment: Take a small subset of the data, like 1000 records, then you can try things manually. Once you have it working manually to your satisfaction, then you can do it on the entire database recording the macro as you go. I would suggest writing down the sequence of steps that you will need to do. If you know how to edit a recorded macro then you can record it on the small data set and then edit the macro so it works ton the full data set. It may be a bit time consuming, but if you can get it working manually then you know you can automate the task with a macro and then save tons of time.